# How to concatenate lists from different ranks into a single list in rank 0?

Tags: python, list, parallel-processing, concatenation, mpi4py

I am creating local lists in different ranks and gathering them in rank 0. I want to create a master list which contains the elements of the local list in order.

My current code is as follows

```py
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

local_list = [i for i in range(rank*2, (rank+1)*2)]

master = []
master = comm.gather(local_list, root=0)
if rank == 0:
    print(master)
```

On runnning this code with 4 proessors, I get the output as:

```
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

But my desired output is:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the `mpi4py` package does, but you can flatten your list with the following code:

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in master for item in sublist]
```